# Responsive website using CSS - adding a panel on an background image

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have the following CSS, and I want to display the form panel at the lower section of the background image.

Background image CSS section:

```
.ban {
    background: transparent url('../../im.jpg') 0 0 no-repeat fixed;
    text-align: center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 600px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 3em;
    display: table;
}
```

Form panel CSS section:

```
.signPanel{
    display: table-cell;
    font-size: 1em;
    margin-top: 0.125em;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 50;

    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px black;
}
```

The HTML part
    
            image comes here

```
    </div>
<form class="signPanel">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Login</legend>

            <input type="email" placeholder="Email"> <input
                type="password" placeholder="Password"> <label
                for="remember"> 
            </label>

            <button type="submit" class="pure-button pure-button">Sign
                in</button>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

The image below will describe what I want to achieve.

[image: The intended result]

Comment: Here you go... I have created a fiddle for you. I would suggest you use position:relative and top in css if you want to move the div. http://jsfiddle.net/5AzAa/2/... Like what @SamiraKhorshidi said, please add a fiddle next time.

Comment: @Minelava For some reason, your solution doesn't work. The panel gets displayed in the black colour area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the complete solution on link below:

http://jsbin.com/oFeFeFal/1/edit?html,css,output

A little CSS trick is to keep the form or anything at the lower section of background or Parennt is to Give relative position to container or .ban div in your case and absolute position to the form or any child element and apply bottom:0 to it. this will make child element float inside its parent.

Comment: This helps, but how do i get the form panel to the middle of the image. I mean center the form panel. Here's my fiddle http://jsbin.com/oFeFeFal/3/

Comment: create another container for form and center it using css, check here: http://jsbin.com/oFeFeFal/4/

Comment: Sorry but i am a bit new to this. Are you hard coding `346px`. Can i center it without hardcoding?

Comment: 346px is actually the width of form, you can change it accordingly. To center elements, all you need is margin from left and right set to auto and float set to none if any. this will make div alignment from left and right to be equal resulting in centering the div.